# error in sendFile HTML file in express.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am triying yo show a file HTML with expressjs with a static __dirname but doasnt show the html after calling localhost/

```js
var express=        require('express'); 
var web=express();

web.use(express.static(__dirname+'/shalimar'));
//Inside /shalimar is located 'home.html'

web.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 console.log("Estoy Cargando desde '/'");
 res.sendFile('home.html');
});
web.listen(4200,function(){          
console.log('Servidor Web Iniciado en el Puerto : 4200')
});
```

the console show e this error

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

How is the correct way to send an html file to local side?

Answer (score 0):

According the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile):

> Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path to the file.

the `root` option can be set in the second param:

```
res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])
```